# imread() permission error after processing same images

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image list contain the image names which I want to batch process, below it's the format of the image list:

```
1286996755-1286996763
1151149321-1151149325
1210402841-1209796794
.....
```

I run the following matlab program to batch process, however, when I run almost the 3500th image, The program throw
an exception which say:

```
Can't open file "/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/SelectImage/1256955924-1256955926.jpg" for reading;
you may not have read permission.
```

In the `image_list.txt` there are 90000 image names, after that error occurs, the following images(the 3500th to 90000th) also
throws the same exception;

What inconceivable is, when I set the image names which throws that exceptions(the 3000th to 90000th in the origin list) as the input list(`image_list.txt`),
The program continue to run almost 3500 image successfully and after that all failed;

I don't think it's the memory problem, since monitor(`htop`) indicated that the running process just take a little memory to use. I have no idea what the problem is;

The program:

```
function ss_demo

addpath(genpath('./SelectiveSearchCodeIJCV/'));
fid=fopen('./image_list.txt');
imnames=textscan(fid, '%s');
imnames=imnames{1};
outpath=fullfile(pwd, './output');
imgdir=fullfile(pwd, '../SelectImage/');

f_debug=fopen('debug.txt', 'w');

for i=1:numel(imnames)
    im_name=fullfile(imgdir, [imnames{i}, '.jpg']);
    % im_name=fullfile(imnames{i});
    try
        im=imread(im_name);
    catch err
        fprintf(f_debug, '%s\n', im_name);
        fprintf(2,'Error message:%s\n', err.message);
        fprintf('Error occur when %s\n', im_name);
        continue
    end
    boxes = selective_search_boxes(im);
    fprintf('processing %d: %s\n', i, imnames{i});
    filename=sprintf('%s/%s_box.txt', outpath, imnames{i});
    fid=fopen(filename, 'w');
    for k=1:size(boxes,1)
        fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d %d\n', boxes(k,1:4));
    end
end
```

Comment: It could be that particular image is corrupted.  Did you actually try opening it up and seeing if you can view an image?  Did you try doing an `imread` call specifically on that file by itself?  Can you reproduce that error just on that file name?  How about opening up that image outside of MATLAB and seeing if you can view an image? Use GIMP or some other photo viewer to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the image is not corrupted and I can view it. Beside, I use the images which throws an error as the input for the program next time, The program can continue running almost 3500 of them successfully.

Comment: Where does the error occur exactly in your code?  The `imread` call?

Comment: Yes, the imread() function throw an exception say that "Can't open file '/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX.jpg' for reading;you may not have read permission."

Comment: Are you experiencing random errors in other areas of your computer? Do you notice programs just randomly shutting down? This sounds more like a problem with RAM.

Comment: Oh,I've figured it out! That's the problem I've forgot to write an `fclose` after a `fopen`. The program shut down since open file limits!. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above forgot to write an `fclose` after an `fopen`. Therefore the program shut down since the open file limits.